# for serverside pagination does the server should have the support for it? any "API" with pagination?

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, pagination

I want to implement pagination in my "angularJs" application. I have a dropdown menu that I'm using `angular-ui` for that. I want at first application loads the first set of data from "API" and when scrolled to button with the help of `ngInfiniteScroll` requests the next set of data from the "API". For example at first in request "URL" I add "page=1" as parameter and for any request I add to that "page" number. 
My question is that for this pagination should the "API" has the pagination capability or I can do this for any "API"?
If the "API" need to have that capability, do you know any "API" with pagination capability so I can test my application?
Appreciate any help.
my code is [here](https://thimble.mozilla.org/en-US/projects/500504/remix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has to support pagination in the sense that it should be able to respond to queries with fragments of data, instead of dumping all the data in one go.

For example:

For page 1:
`your.api.endpoint/your/resource/path/countries?offset=0&pageSize=50`

For page 4:
`your.api.endpoint/your/resource/path/countries?offset=200&pageSize=50`

You can build your URL params for pagination however you want though, e.g. `/countries?pageNo=4&pageSize=50`, `/countries?from=200&to=250` etc.

Note:

When you implement server-side pagination, you need to implement server-side sorting and filtering too; that's because with server-side pagination the client can only see 1 page of data and therefore sorting or filtering would be inaccurate.

**EDIT to show example of mocking API response**

In your service you might have something like this:

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'your.api.endpoint/your/resource/path/countries?offset=200&pageSize=50'
})
```

And you'd replace it with:

```
var pageOfData = { ... }; // Mocked data here.
return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(pageOfData);
});
```

Comment: thnk you for explaining do you know any api with pagination capability that I can test my app with?

Comment: Are you not building your own API?

Comment: Then tell whoever is doing the back-end that the API needs to support pagination

Comment: Ok but I have to implement it in my FronEnd so I need to test it first

Comment: Then clarify with them how the API will work and mock the replies in your services.